# Grayscale image turns black when it is displayed in applet

Tags: java, image, applet, grayscale

IBM content manager stores all my images in grayscale but when I retrieve it and displays in applet,The grayscale doesn't converts in binary or remains as it is but it turns all black.

What can be the issue?

Should I convert grayscale image to binary before it renders on applet?

Edit:
I am using TViewerApplet.java from here http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cmgmt/v8r4m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.samples.doc%2Fsamples%2Fjava%2Fviewer%2Freadme.html

And Calling it from below code

```
<BODY>
<table width="100%" border="1">
<tr>
<td width="100%">
<applet name="viewerApplet" id="TViewerApplet" width="100%" height="500" align="baseline" code="com.bsli.applet.TViewerApplet.class" codebase="./classes" mayscript="mayscript" archive="cmbview81.jar">    
</applet>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var name = '<%=request.getParameter("name")%>';
    alert('name..' + name);
    var host = '<%=request.getLocalName()%>';
    var port = '<%=request.getLocalPort()%>';
    var contextPath = '<%=request.getContextPath()%>';

    var url = "http://"+host+":"+port+contextPath+"/CMServlet.jsp?pid="+pid;
    alert('url..'+url);
    url = encodeURI(url);   
    window.document.viewerApplet.check_setInfo_openDocument(pid,url,name,'<%=request.getParameter("userid")%>');

</script>
</BODY>
```

Comment: How is your applet gets images?

Comment: It is still not clear. You say '... but when I retrieve it and displays in applet,...' so how your applet 'retrieves' image? Is it takes images from LFS? Could you show the related problem code?